# Getting started with git-svn, I'm missing something

Tags: git-svn

OK, so I've managed to

```
git svn clone http://repository/project MyProj
```

And that gives me this hierarchy

```
Project 
 |
 |____branches
 |
 |____tags
 |
 |____trunk
```

I was kind of hoping that in `gitk --all` I would see those branches translated into git branches. Was I expecting too much?

The question is, where do I go from here? Do I just work inside one of the branch folders?

**UPDATE**

For others hit by this problem, the reason it wasn't working for me is that I thought that the path to my SVN project was `http://repository/project`, where as actually it was `http://repository/project/subproject`, so git-svn wasn't finding the branches/tags/trunk in the expected place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
mkdir MyProj
cd MyProj
git svn init http://repository/project --stdlayout
```

This tells `git svn` that trunk/tags/branches are to be expected in your project, and that branches should be treated as git branches.

Comment: Excellent! Actually, what I was also missing was the WHOLE path to my project -> I'd stopped at http://repository/, so I wasn't getting all the goodness...